# Renaming a table column by its sub-string in KDB?

Tags: kdb

How would i rename a column in KDB with its substring?

Example:

**Initial Table**

```
    name  | number
------------------
  foo/bar |  999
  foo/log |  999
  foo/ton |  999
  foo/tin |  999
```

The query should truncate the `name` column by a certain delimiter, in the case the `/` character.

**Resultant Table 1**

```
    name  | number
------------------
    foo   |  999
    foo   |  999
    foo   |  999
    foo   |  999
```

Or remove a sub-string between the string i.e. the `/` character.

**Resultant Table 2**

```
    name  | number
------------------
   foobar |  999
   foolog |  999
   footon |  999
   footin |  999
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can go about this.

```
t:([name:("foo/bar";"foo/log";"foo/ton";"foo/tin")]number:999 999 999 999)
```

You can you [vs](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/vs/) which allows you to split a string on a separator. Eg. the below returns a nested list of the two constituent strings which made up the original string.

```
q)"/" vs "foo/bar"
"foo"
"bar"
```

From here you can then choose the string you wish to use in the updated column.

```
q)last "/" vs "foo/bar"
"bar"
```

Or can combine the output to one string using raze.

```
q)raze "/" vs "foo/bar"
"foobar"
```

You can then use these methods in an update statement for your table. In this case I am using [each-right](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) with the sv operator so that each string in the name column is operated upon. You could also use a function to be called with each string. (eg. `update name:{last "/" vs x}each name from t`)

```
q)update raze each  "/" vs/: name from t
name    | number
--------| ------
"foobar"| 999
"foolog"| 999
"footon"| 999
"footin"| 999
q)update last each  "/" vs/: name from t
name | number
-----| ------
"bar"| 999
"log"| 999
"ton"| 999
"tin"| 999
q)update first each  "/" vs/: name from t
name | number
-----| ------
"foo"| 999
"foo"| 999
"foo"| 999
"foo"| 999
```

For your first resultant table, if your filepath is always the same length a simpler method could be using the take operator on each string like below.

```
q)update 3#'name from t
name | number
-----| ------
"foo"| 999
"foo"| 999
"foo"| 999
"foo"| 999
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solutions work fine. How would I go about segmenting a string with two delimiters then? i.e. "foo/bar/thing" -> "bar/thing" or "bar"

Comment: No problem. As vs results in a nested list, if I had >2 outputs, I would use simple indexing to get the element I would like. 
Eg. `("/" vs "foo/bar/thing")[1]` to give "bar". To get "bar/thing" (aside from just dropping the "foo" with 4_), I would use sv on the elements I want to combine.  `"/" sv ("/" vs "foo/bar/thing")[1 2]`. sv is essentially the opposite to vs in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where you just want to remove substring, another option is to use `ssr` which will replace all occurrences of substring with target string/character.

```
q) t:([name:("foo/bar";"foo/bar/thing")]number:999 1000)
```

```
name           | number
---------------| ------
"foo/bar"      | 999   
"foo/bar/thing"| 1000
```

```
q) update ssr[;"/";""]@'name from t
```

Output:

```
name         | number
-------------| ------
"foobar"     | 999   
"foobarthing"| 1000
```